# Regular NPM package not functioning within Vue.js app

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm trying to use NPM package [scroll-ease-efficient](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scroll-ease-efficient) in my `Nuxt`/`Vue` app, so I've created a file called `scroll-ease-efficient.client.js` in `plugins/` folder that I specified in the `plugins` section of my `nuxt.config.js` file.

Here is the content of the file:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import { scrollTo } from 'scroll-ease-efficient'
Vue.use(scrollTo)
```

Then in my app I simply do:

```
const scrollEle = document.getElementById('element')
scrollTo(scrollEle, 500)
```

This should work but it does nothing, and I have no console error either.

What's wrong?

Comment: I should add that Vue plugins used with `Vue.use()` have to subscribe to a specific interface: it should have an `install` method that takes two arguments: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html#Writing-a-Plugin. Objects that do not meet this requirement cannot be used as a plugin.

Comment: pls consider it to behave as expected - `scrollTo(undefined)` just does nothing: https://github.com/TheoXiong/scroll-ease-efficient/blob/56770e1618745370bccf2880e93d514cdb355eeb/index.js#L43

Comment: But my element does get selected and `scrollEle` is correctly defined

Answer (score 3):

thanks for asking. But first, let me clarify. Not all npm package is intended to be installed using Vue/Nuxt plugin method. The regular npm package name for this way often contains word vue/nuxt, like `Vuetify` or `Vuefire`.

And `scroll-ease-efficient` package isn't vue nor nuxt plugin. So in order to use this package, you can add global api from that package to vue or nuxt constructor.

```
import Vue from "vue";
import { scrollTo } from "scroll-ease-efficient";

Vue.prototype.$scrollTo = scrollTo;
```

Now you can access the global method through `this.$scrollTo()`

---

**Edit**

Please checkout this link for the demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-scroll-ease-efficient-demo-8tqmj

Comment: Thanks, still doesn't do anything though

Comment: @drake035 Hi I made a demo, please check out the link on the edited section above.

Comment: My question relates to a Nuxt/Vue app not just a regular Vue app. I know it's not specified in the title but it is in the first line of the question

Comment: I think the problem here is not on the vue or nuxt app itself, but on the documentation of the scroll-ease-efficient. At first, I also had hard time figure out how to make it worked on my demo links. Then I decided to just copy and paste the code of their demo to my demo.

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't answer the question